# Cooldown between api requests

Tags: ios, swift, combine

The API provider requires performing requests no more often than 1 second. How can this limitation be implemented using Combine in my `request` method?

```
func request<T: Codable>(components: URLComponents) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: components.url!)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

So I would like to get from this:

```
Request1 - 0.0 sec
Request2 - 0.3 sec
Request3 - 0.6 sec
Request4 - 0.9 sec
Request5 - 1.2 sec
```

... something like that:

```
Request1 - 0.0 sec
Request2 - 1.0 sec
Request3 - 2.0 sec
Request4 - 3.0 sec
Request5 - 4.0 sec
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
extension URLSession {
    func dataTaskPublisher(url: URL, timeout: UInt32, queue: DispatchQueue) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        return Future<Data, Error> { promise in
            queue.async {
                self.dataTask(with: url) { data, url, error in
                    if let data = data {
                        promise(.success(data))
                    }
                    if let error = error {
                        promise(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
                .resume()
                sleep(timeout)
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue()

func request<T: Codable>(components: URLComponents) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(url: components.url!, timeout: 1, queue: queue)
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it in RxSwift. Combine doesn't have a `concatMap` operator, so I'm not sure what a translation would look like. You can use the below in your Combine code with the [RxCombine](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/RxCombine) library.

```
class API {
    let urlSession: URLSession
    let subject = PublishSubject<URLRequest>()
    let result: Observable<(Event<Data>, URLRequest)>

    init(urlSession: URLSession = URLSession.shared) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
        result = subject
            .concatMap { [urlSession] request in
                Observable.combineLatest(
                    urlSession.rx.data(request: request).materialize(),
                    Observable.just(request).delay(.seconds(1), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).startWith(request)
                )
                .distinctUntilChanged { _, _ in true }
            }
    }

    func request<T>(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<T> where T: Decodable {
        subject.onNext(request)
        return result
            .filter { $0.1 == request }
            .map { $0.0 }
            .take(1)
            .dematerialize()
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
    }
}
```